# Ошибка при запуске проекта c использованием hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Столкнулся с ошибкой следующего рода (смотреть скрин)[image: первый слайд]В проекте создал cfg.xml и cfm.xml в main вызвал  SessionFactory factory;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        factory = new Configuration().configure("cfg/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    CrudPersonals crudPersonals = new CrudPersonals();
    crudPersonals.addUsers("dd", "ch");
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Использую IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Это для обычного Java вам нужно или для Spring?

Comment: для обычного java

Comment: @ДмитрийЧуешов ссори, что так долго. Ваша проблема решилась? P.S. тегайте человека, корому хотите ответить, чтобы легко было Вас найти)

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, и вставьте текст вместо картинки. Код в виде картинки нельзя скопировать и запустить у себя - и это очень сильно снижает шанс, что вам кто-то поможет.